# How can I prevent a panel from being closed?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalondock

I am using AvalonDock (V2) with a DocumentsSource:

```
<a:DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

I would like to disable the possibility to close a panel using a Style or something that works with a DocuemntsSource.

If possible I would like to have the closing Element to dock in a collapsed manner to the DocumentManager instead of closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are intrested: there is a CanClose Propery that can be bound...

Answer (score 0):

The CanClose() property is not working for LayoutAnchorable control.

But it can work if you can change the source code to disable the close button.

In my case I had to go in that route.